# Designing a synchronizable embedded collection with MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I'd like to give an example for a design decision I'm struggling with:

Let's say I have a "To Do List" application, with each list defined as a MongoDB document, and its items defined as an embedded collection.

This is pretty straightforward, but now I want to add a kind of "fork" feature, so my friends could copy my document, and have the items automatically synced whenever I make changes to them on *my original document*.

That is, when I add, rename, remove or reorder items in *my* list, I will be able to update their list, while still keeping *their items* checked/unchecked.

Here are some ideas, but I'm new to MongoDB and just can't tell how hard each is to implement, which is preferable and can't see all the possible issues that may arise:

- **The RDBMS way:** Keep the items as a separate collection, each one referenced by a "checked/unchecked" item embedded in the list (essentially a many-to-many relationship).
- **Reference original items:** Each embedded copied item will reference its counterpart in the original document, this way I can tell if the original was renamed, deleted or newly added.

Can anyone provide any insight that can help decide on the solution?

**UPDATE:**

As part of the user experience, I'd like to let the owner of a copied document to decide whether or not to update his list, so I think the first implementation wouldn't quite work for that.

But how is it possible to keep track of the changes with the second approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend going after your first approach. For example, if this is an item:

```
{
   "_id" : 123,
   "Name" : "Feed the cat"
}
```

You would make a todo list document like this:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "items" : [ 123, ... ]
}
```

The reason I would recommend this is because keeping embedded documents that change quite often in sync ... is very difficult. If an embedded document is going to appear all over, then it's far easier to have one authoritative version of the document and then just link to that document's id.

This should allow for a copied todo list to diverge from the original list of items as well. They are just references to another collection. You could add/remove/edit all you want.

Comment: This does help, but makes me reconsider my problem a little. I'd really like to let the copies stay the same until their owner actively decides to sync them with the original. In this case the first approach isn't quite fitting.